# Get an Error when use IoThub as the Job input

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

I create an IotHub and create an eventprocesshost to receive the events from the hub in a console application, then I create an ASA job and make the Iothub as the input with the default consumer group, but when I start the job, I get the exception:

*There is more than one receiver with different epoch value connected to the same Event Hub. Please ensure Service Bus Explorer or an EventProcessorHost application is not connected while Stream Analytics job is running.*

**So the job input and the event processor host use the same consumer group make this happen???
The input and host cannot use the same consumer group???**

Comment: You can find out more about epochs here: You can find more information about epochs here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gyan/2014/09/02/event-hubs-receiver-epoch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have EPH and ASA job running side by side due to Epoch conflict. Please close your EPH application and then restart ASA job.